# CSS vertical menu with description below

Tags: css, menu, html

I am trying to create a vertical menu that looks like this (think of the cubes as placeholders for icons):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWWzR.png

I am having trouble putting the description below the main text, which is an `<a>` of course. Here is what I have so far in the HTML code:

```
<div id="actions">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Element 1</a><span class="desc">Description</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Element 2</a><span class="desc">Description</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
#actions {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
}

#actions ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#actions ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #64ADD0;
}

#actions a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#actions a:hover {
    color: #3CA0D0;
}

#actions .desc {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

However, the result is that the description appears to the right of the link, and furthermore, the `<span>` isn't part of the link, so it shows as an ordinary label. How can I fix this? I am new to CSS and web design in general so please excuse me if this is a dumb question. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `inline` in your `inline-block;` that will make the anchor take up the whole line and push anything after it to the next line.

```
#actions a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmbLR/

Comment: Thanks, that worked. :) Now if I put the span inside the `<a>` (basically, what I want is to create a big "button"), it gets the same color and hover effect as the title, what is the best way to fix that? Force the style in the ".desc" rule?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the follow CSS rule

```
#actions > ul > li > a {
   display: block;
}
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E7qMU/)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use float:left and clear:both in order to know exactly where the objects are located: http://jsfiddle.net/MAt8Y/

```
#actions .desc {

    line-height: 20px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#actions a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
    float:left;
}
```